# Filter a queryset by a list of users and request.user at the same time

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a queryset containing posts from both a list of 'friends' and 'request.user'.

So far I can only filter posts by friends using `posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=friends)`.
I tried to do `posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=friends).filter(user=request.user)` but this returns an empty queryset.

I can't figure out how to filter 'posts' using both parameters at the same time.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here you filter in such way that the `user` should be in the list of friends *and* it should be `request.user`. Which will likely not work.

You can here use [**`Q`**-objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to make a logical or:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Post.objects.filter(Q(user__in=friends) | Q(user=request.user))
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q)  like this

```
from django.db.models import Q

Post.objects.filter(Q(user__in=friends)|Q(user=request.user))
```